# Rails 4 nested form issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm using the nested form plugin and trying to make it work for rails 4 instead of rails 3. Basically my model looks like this:

```
has_many :item, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :item, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:item].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

and my view looks like this:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@store) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :item do |item_form| %>
     <%= item_form.text_field :name %>
     <%= item_form.link_to_remove "Remove this item" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

this works (in terms of presentation - you can add and delete fields like you should be able to) but doesn't save the item names.

I tried this in my controller (these are the protected attributes/params):

```
def store_params
  params.require(:store).permit(:name, :owner, :description,:url, :user, item_attributes)
end
```

but it still comes up with:

```
Unpermitted parameters: item_attributes
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: You will probably have to allow the fields of item as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, but the nested_form gem does not explicitly support Rails 4.

Comment: Try [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem instead. Seems to be a good way to go with Rails 4.0 because it's a bit more updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to permit the fields of item (like name) to be allowed as well.

So try this:

```
def store_params
    params.require(:store).permit(:name, :owner, :description,:url, :user, item_attributes: [:name])
end
```

Answer (score 5):

sometimes you have to specify the :id like this:

```
def store_params
    params.require(:store).permit(:name, :owner, :description,:url, :user, item_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

in a similar case I had last week, not specifying the :id made Rails 4 create an new entity instead of updating the existing one.

Comment: This. Adding :id fixed it so that I wasn't multiplying the list on every submit. I also had to add :_destroy if I wanted my nested form to delete properly.

I wonder if there's some way to whitelist the entire _attributes without resorting to permit!